# Is there a way to have a "full-screen" mode (no frames, just the web), but in a window (not covering the whole screen) in chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, fullscreen

Maybe an extension that would help it? Some tweak? I would e.g. open youtube on full screen but make the window smaller (non-fullscreen) and move it to a bottom right corner, so I would only see the video (similar to youtube app on Android) and then I would use a proprietary app to keep it always on top (e.g. Dexpot / autohotkey).

All I would need to hide is the panel with the tabs and buttons, addressbar with extensions. (just like when fullscreened)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the web application you're using has an option or a button to toggle full screen, the **[Picture in Picture Viewer](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/picture-in-picture-viewer/efaagmolahogmekmnmkigonhfcdiemnl)** Google Chrome extension might do the job for you.

---

**Setup**

- Go to  [chrome://flags/#enable-panels](http://chrome://flags/#enable-panels) and enable panels
- Relaunch Chrome

**Use**

- Navigate to a website of your choice
- Activate the Picture in Picture Viewer extension

  - This should open the website in a panel
- From within the panel, toggle the presentation mode for the website you're on
- (Optional) Resize the panel to suit your needs

**Note**

- The keyboard shortcut to toggle full screen will not work. This extension works well for websites that have some option to trigger the full screen from the page itself.

Comment: Still holds the panel up with the name of the window, but otherwise it is a pretty good working solution, thanks.